# How do I build this SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table `tblFSIC` which consist of `Id`, `BIN` , `SerialNumber`, and `year`

I want to check if there already a `SerialNumber` on other `BIN`:

The query I use was:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblFSIC 
WHERE ControlNumber = @ControlNumber AND NOT BIN = @BIN;
```

**But** I also need to check if the `BIN` and `Year` has duplicate, and my query for that:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblFSIC 
WHERE BIN = @BIN AND Year = @Year;
```

The first think of using:

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM tblFSIC 
 WHERE (ControlNumber = @ControlNumber AND NOT BIN = @BIN) 
    OR (BIN = @BIN AND Year = @Year);
```

But it will just return any `ControlNumber` that has different `BIN`;

I have no idea on how do I fit 2 different conditions on query

Comment: provide some sample data and your expected output in table format

Comment: This looks to be part of a stored proc since it has the `@` on some of the columns used in the sample code. If that is the case, could you share the code in it's entirety for ease of review and debugging?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want aggregation:

```
SELECT SerialNumber
FROM tblFSIC 
GROUP BY SerialNumber
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN ControlNumber = @ControlNumber AND NOT BIN = @BIN THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
       SUM(CASE WHEN BIN = @BIN AND Year = @Yea THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0;
```

This finds serial numbers that meet both conditions.  Use `= 0` in the having if you want serial numbers that fail both conditions.